# Play Framework Compile Error: '(' expected but ')' found

Tags: java, html, scala, intellij-idea, playframework

When I attempting to compile my Play Framework 2. project, I receive this error: '(' expected but ')' found.
What I'm trying to do is : 'After a failed login attempt, user should get feedback. If the login attempt fails server side, show error messages on page after the failed request. Could someone please help me out.

I added the string that I want to display on the form after a failed login attempt as below:

```
if (response.hasErrors()) {
return ok(create.render(createViewModelForm, "invalid username or password"));
```

And on the **create.scala.html**

```
@if (!@errorMessage.isEmpty()) {
  <div>@errorMessage</div>
  }
```

[image: This is the error that I get when I compile]

This is the **SessionsController.java**   > ui\controllers\SessionsController

```
package femr.ui.controllers;

import com.google.inject.Inject;
import femr.business.services.core.ISessionService;
import femr.business.services.core.IUserService;
import femr.common.dtos.CurrentUser;
import femr.common.dtos.ServiceResponse;
import femr.data.models.core.IUser;
import femr.ui.models.sessions.CreateViewModel;
import femr.ui.views.html.sessions.create;
import femr.ui.views.html.sessions.editPassword;
import femr.util.calculations.dateUtils;
import femr.util.stringhelpers.StringUtils;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.Days;
import play.data.Form;
import play.data.FormFactory;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class SessionsController extends Controller {

    private final FormFactory formFactory;
    private final ISessionService sessionsService;
    private final IUserService userService;

    @Inject
    public SessionsController(FormFactory formFactory, ISessionService sessionsService, IUserService userService) {

        this.formFactory = formFactory;
        this.sessionsService = sessionsService;
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    public Result createGet() {
        CurrentUser currentUser = sessionsService.retrieveCurrentUserSession();

        final Form<CreateViewModel> createViewModelForm = formFactory.form(CreateViewModel.class);

        if (currentUser != null) {
            return redirect(routes.HomeController.index());
        }

        return ok(create.render(createViewModelForm));
    }

    public Result createPost() {

        final Form<CreateViewModel> createViewModelForm = formFactory.form(CreateViewModel.class);
        CreateViewModel viewModel = createViewModelForm.bindFromRequest().get();
        ServiceResponse<CurrentUser> response = sessionsService.createSession(viewModel.getEmail(), viewModel.getPassword(), request().remoteAddress());

        if (response.hasErrors()) {
            return ok(create.render(createViewModelForm));
        }else{
            IUser user = userService.retrieveById(response.getResponseObject().getId());
            user.setLastLogin(dateUtils.getCurrentDateTime());
            ServiceResponse<IUser> userResponse = userService.update(user, false);
            if (userResponse.hasErrors()){
                throw new RuntimeException();
            }

            DateTime start = new DateTime(user.getPasswordCreatedDate());
            DateTime stop = new DateTime(DateTime.now());
            int daysBetween = Days.daysBetween(start, stop).getDays();

            if(daysBetween > 60){
                user.setPasswordReset(true);
            }

            if (user.getPasswordReset() == true){
                return editPasswordGet(user);
            }
        }

        return redirect(routes.HomeController.index());

    }

    public Result editPasswordGet(IUser user){

        final Form<CreateViewModel> createViewModelForm = formFactory.form(CreateViewModel.class);

        return ok(editPassword.render(user.getFirstName(), user.getLastName(), createViewModelForm, new ArrayList<String>()));
    }

    public Result editPasswordPost(){

        final Form<CreateViewModel> createViewModelForm = formFactory.form(CreateViewModel.class);
        CreateViewModel viewModel = createViewModelForm.bindFromRequest().get();
        CurrentUser currentUser = sessionsService.retrieveCurrentUserSession();
        IUser user = userService.retrieveById(currentUser.getId());
        Boolean isNewPassword = false;

        Pattern hasUppercase = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]");
        Pattern hasNumber = Pattern.compile("\\d");
        ArrayList<String> messages = new ArrayList<>();
        if (StringUtils.isNullOrWhiteSpace(viewModel.getNewPassword()))
            messages.add("password is a required field");
        else
        {
            if(viewModel.getNewPassword().length() < 6)        //AJ Saclayan Password Constraints
                messages.add("password is less than 6 characters");
            if (!hasUppercase.matcher(viewModel.getNewPassword()).find())
                    messages.add("password must have an uppercase");
            if (!hasNumber.matcher(viewModel.getNewPassword()).find())
                    messages.add("password must have a number");
            if(!viewModel.getNewPassword().equals(viewModel.getNewPasswordVerify()))
                messages.add("passwords do not match");
            //check if new password is equal to the old password
            if(userService.checkOldPassword(viewModel.getNewPassword(),userService.retrieveById(currentUser.getId()).getPassword()))
                messages.add("password must not be the same one used before reset");


        }

        if(!messages.isEmpty())
            return ok(editPassword.render(user.getFirstName(), user.getLastName(), createViewModelForm, messages));
        else
        {
            user.setPassword(viewModel.getNewPassword());
            user.setPasswordCreatedDate(DateTime.now());
            user.setPasswordReset(false);
            isNewPassword = true;
        }

        ServiceResponse<IUser> userResponse = userService.update(user, isNewPassword);
        if (userResponse.hasErrors()){
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
        return redirect(routes.HomeController.index());
    }

    public Result delete() {
        sessionsService.invalidateCurrentUserSession();

        return redirect(routes.HomeController.index());
    }
}
```

This is the createForm in ui\views\sessions

```
@(gcreateForm: Form[femr.ui.models.sessions.CreateViewModel], errorMessage: java.lang.String)

@import femr.ui.views.html.layouts.main
@import femr.ui.controllers.routes.SessionsController
    @styles = {
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("css/login.css")">
    }
@main("Login", styles = styles) {

    @helper.form(action = SessionsController.createPost(), 'class -> "form-signin") {
        <div id="login">
            <h1>Please sign in</h1>
            @if (!@errorMessage.isEmpty()) {
                <div>@errorMessage</div>
            }
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
            <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
            <img src="@routes.Assets.versioned("img/logo_color_sm.png")" />
        </div>
    }
}
```

**HomeController.java**

```
package femr.ui.controllers;

import com.google.inject.Inject;
import femr.common.dtos.CurrentUser;
import femr.business.services.core.ISessionService;
import femr.ui.views.html.home.index;
import femr.ui.views.html.sessions.create;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;

public class HomeController extends Controller {

    private ISessionService sessionService;

    @Inject
    public HomeController(ISessionService sessionService) {
        this.sessionService = sessionService;
    }

    public Result index() {
        CurrentUser currentUser = sessionService.retrieveCurrentUserSession();

        if (null != currentUser) {
            return ok(index.render(currentUser));
        }
        return ok(create.render(null));
    }

}
```

Comment: It looks like the error is in something that's neither Java nor HTML, so you might want to choose a tag that will attract StackOverflow readers who are experts in whatever you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try using: `@if(!errorMessage.isEmpty()) {`

Corresponding twirl doc [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTemplates#If-blocks).

Comment: Now getting error  " not  found: value errorMessage " using 
                                                                       
   @if(!errorMessage.isEmpty()) {                                                                            Trying to review the twirl doc.

Answer (score 0):

1 - When you have an expression like this you don't need to add the @ on the variable because it is already inside a scala code block.

2 -  `errorMessage: java.lang.String`, Change your variable type to only `String` I guess it is better if you use Scala string there *may* be some differences for the template engine.

`@if (!errorMessage.isEmpty()) {
    <div>@errorMessage</div>
}`

Comment: @Frederic A.                                                                                                I applied the changed as you had suggested and now I get a different error when compiling.

Comment: Compilation error

method render in class femr.ui.views.html.sessions.create cannot be applied to given types;
  required: play.data.Form<femr.ui.models.sessions.CreateViewModel>,java.lang.String
  found: <nulltype>
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
In \app\femr\ui\controllers\HomeController.java:27 
23
        if (null != currentUser) {

Comment: 24
            return ok(index.render(currentUser));
25
        }
26

27
        return ok(create.render(null));
28
    }

Comment: update the error on your question and not on the comments. Your view has TWO parameters, then you need to pass an instance of the `form` and the `string` with the error that you have.